# Read File data from MSI custom action for remote CLR installation

Tags: sql-server, windows-installer, installshield, sqlclr

We need to be able to install an assembly to a remote SQL Server database during an MSI installation. In order to do this, we have a SQL script with a replacement tag where the assembly data (hex encoded with the `0x` prefix) should go. Now I need to figure out how to make a custom action read the binary file data for the assembly from the MSI file, and put the hex content into a property that InstallShield's "SQL Scripts" action can substitute into the SQL script.

I'm stuck at the point where I need to read the binary file data from the MSI file. I could wait until the deferred context to read the file data from the file system after it's installed, but that doesn't seem to be the way MSI "wants" to operate seeing as how it makes accessing properties so difficult in the deferred action context. I'm not even sure I would still be able to modify the SQL script at that point - it would probably be too late. I think the "right" way to do this is to have the SQL script that will be executed already determined before the deferred action phase begins.

I'm looking for a solution better than my backup plan of having the build process replace the content in the SQL script at build time (because that means we essentially deliver two copies of the file, one for reference/maintenance purposes, and the other included in SQL script).

So how can I read the binary content of a file that MSI will install from a custom action, or is there a better way to install an assembly for a CLR to a remote SQL server?

Comment: I wouldn't be so bold to make this statement but I know many think stored procs are "evil".  One thing to consider would be does the benefits of this managed code out weigh the deployment / integration complications?   Could it be refactored and eliminated and be a net positive to the system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend doing what you are trying to avoid doing ;-), and that is having the build process create the SQL script with the `CREATE ASSEMBLY [name] FROM 0x....` in it.

> I'm looking for a solution better than my backup plan of having the build process replace the content in the SQL script at build time (because that means we essentially deliver two copies of the file, one for reference/maintenance purposes, and the other included in SQL script).

I disagree with the conclusion here. You only need the script with the `FROM 0x....` in it. You do not need to keep one that references a path to a DLL. That is not very portable, even outside of the MSI installer scenario. From an SDLC ("Software Development Life Cycle" for those wondering about that acronym) perspective, it is best to have a release script that is self-contained: no external dependency on a DLL somewhere on the file system. And from a "reference" perspective, there is not much benefit to having the DLL outside of possibly viewing its code using [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) or Red Gate's [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/), and that would just be to verify what was "shipped" since you have the actual source code.

The only times I ever bother with the DLL is for demos, presentations, and articles. When it comes to integrating something into a build process, I just read the DLL into a string of hex codes, broken at every Nth character with a back-slash (`\`) as the final character of the line since that is the T-SQL line-continuation character. An example of this is the following SQL script on Pastebin.com:

[SQLCLR Meta-data function for cross-database IndexName()](http://pastebin.com/K67wbiPu)

That script installs an Assembly and creates a Function as a working example of the code I posted in this DBA.StackExchange answer:

[Central stored procedure to execute in calling database context](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44764/central-stored-procedure-to-execute-in-calling-database-context/112353#112353)

Comment: Yeah, I've been plumbing the depths of FDICreate and the functions for extracting data from a CAB file to try to work around this at install time instead of build time, but it may not be worth the effort. Thanks for pushing me back onto the path of sanity.

Comment: I should also note that, with the product as large as it is, I can't rule out the possibility that the same assemblies being installed into the database might also be referenced from other non-database code. So we might still end up with duplicates, but it's a small price to pay.

Comment: FWIW, I appreciate DRY but I wouldn't apply it in this case.  So the MSI is a little larger.  Not the end of the world.  It doesn't really make your system any harder to maintain as it's all automated.  Just my $.02.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a blog article somewhere around here on this topic.

I've written a lot of installers with database requirements and I've pretty much come to the conclusion to not try to execute scripts against a remote database.  There are just too many things that can go wrong and the MSI's understanding of "installed" just gets out of sync when it's another machine or machines.

There have been times when I just decided to break the database feature out into it's own MSI and run it directly on the data tier server.  Now the application tier merely gets the connection string, validates the compatibility and configures the app to use it.

Just a thought.

Comment: We generally don't track the installed state of anything purely database-related; our scripts just force the database to the desired state, and we never remove anything from the database once it's there. We do have a separate database installer specifically for cases when the SQL server is separate, but we haven't had to make this part of it. It's nice to have a single installer for the case when everything is one one server. Your thought is interesting, though, and something I may revisit if I encounter challenges on this path.

Comment: It's a paradigm conflict for sure.  MSI is very much in the track the state and support resilency / repair / upgrade / uninstall and so on.  There is no one size fits all so ya just something to think about.   Many applications (take TFS setup for example ) punt it to an application configuration utility.   Some of my applications just have a local database that is pretty much disposable (say code tables and such) so I might actually destroy those on uninstall.  For some more ramblings see: http://blog.iswix.com/2008/10/rfc-sql-scripts-are-almost-declared.html

Comment: One more thought... how would you address this DLL from a DR perspective?  What if someone backed up the user databases, the SQL tier crashed and was rebuilt and the database restored?  How would you get this DLL back into place?  Would your code gracefully surface an error saying a dependency was missing?

Comment: PS- I just remembered one of my concerns.  Impersonate vs No Impersonate and SSPI doesn't always play nice when trying to plan for SQL script execution on a local vs a remote machine.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN and Christopher, based on comments from both of you I think there's a slight misunderstanding about SQLCLR Assemblies. there are no external dependencies. There is no reference to the DLL on the file system. the DLL is never needed which is why I mainly just use the `FROM 0x.. ` syntax. So even if the assembly is also used by the app, there is no duplicate.

Comment: If an application running on the file system (completely unrelated to SQL server) references the assembly directly rather than calling the database or loading it from the database (which is possible by handling the AssemblyLoad event), then it would need to be accessible in the filesystem. But I see your comment is probably mostly directed as Christopher's comment about a missing dependency. It's hard to think of a case where restoring a database with an older version of the assembly (or missing assembly) would report missing dependencies rather than just schema difference problems.

Comment: @srutzky, I was wondering. Thanks for clearing up.  I thought it was more like the old XPCmdShell where it had to be resolved on disk.  I've worked on a lot of installs but there is always something new to learn about the platform and the stack.  There's an old saying that you don't know what you don't know so I always ask paranoid what-if questions when reviewing something. If the answer is no worries we are covered then awesome!

Comment: @BlueMonkMN and Christopher: 1) yes, there can't be a missing dependency like with extended stored procs which do reference the external DLL. This is one benefit of SQLCLR, the assembly is stored in the DB. 2) if the app needs the DLL then fine, but that has nothing to do with SQL Server, which is why using `FROM 0x...` is best. It removes that external dependency from the release script. If the DLL of the same code is on the file system for the app, then ok. If that DLL is also loaded into the GAC, then the assembly in SQL Server is verified that it's the same so you can't have a mismatch.

Comment: Good to know.  Thank you!